# Verification of Payment api of Payu is not working

Tags: asp.net, payment-gateway, payu

I am trying to integrate PayU in my website, I have successfully done the payment api part. Now I am trying to call verification api of transaction. I have followed all the steps from [documentation](https://devguide.payu.in/api/integration-apis/transaction-verification-apis/verify_payment-api/).

Method POST:https://test.payu.in/merchant/postservice?form=2

Image
[image]

I am getting, *Sorry Some Problem Occurred* without any proper error message.

I am stuck on this. Please help.
Any help or comment will be highly appreciated.

My code: Function to make string(in expected format given in the documentation) and Hash using SHA256

```
    {               string command = "verify_payment";
                    string finalStringToBeHashed = PAYU_KEY +"|"+ command + "|" + transactionId + "|" + PAYU_SALT;
                    string hash = _iPayUServices.GetSHA256(finalStringToBeHashed);
                    return Ok(( hash, finalStringToBeHashed));
    }
```

and I am confident that my GetSHA256() function is correct. (As it working for payment api's).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `https://test.payu.in/merchant/postservice?form=2` URL,
use `https://info.payu.in/merchant/postservice?form=2`.

Actually They are upgrading their documentation, so many things are missing as of now. Hopefully, they will add this soon.

Comment: this is bad, usually their links for live starts with secure.payu